# What does "gag-for-gag" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

From [an online article](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/inbetweeners-movie/review/):

> Like any holiday, it is episodic and suffers from repetition but this is **gag-for-gag** the funniest film of the summer and a fitting end to a much-loved series.

A gag is a joke. But what is "gag-for-gag" and what is this construction?

Comment: Have you heard phrases like "word-for-word"? As in "He copied my exam paper *word-for-word*". I think you can get the idea.

Comment: @user3169 I have. It didn't make sense to me the first time I read it. But this time around it does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joke-for-joke.  Each joke of this film is funnier than any joke of any other film released this summer. The reviewer's opinion is that if one compares this film to any other comedy film of this summer, on a joke-by-joke basis, this film will be considered the funnier.